# How to remove the related videos at end of YouTube embedded video?

Tags: video, youtube, url-parameters

I am trying to get the embedded videos to stop showing at the end of the embedded YouTube videos on my website. I have tried the `?rel=0` and it does not work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As of September 2018 Youtube has made it impossible to remove related videos.  You will always get related videos from now on.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  The [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) says they are deprecating the parameters that had been used to disable related videos.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube [changed the `rel=0` parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018) as of September 2018 so that it no longer fully disables related videos.

**However, you can work around this using the YouTube Player API to show custom HTML instead of related videos**.

Here is some example code that displays a custom "replay" button over the video once it completes, hiding the related videos:

```
<style>
    #playerWrap {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    #playerWrap.shown::after {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: black;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center; 
        background-size: 64px 64px;
        background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTI4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNTEwIDUxMCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI1NSAxMDJWMEwxMjcuNSAxMjcuNSAyNTUgMjU1VjE1M2M4NC4xNSAwIDE1MyA2OC44NSAxNTMgMTUzcy02OC44NSAxNTMtMTUzIDE1My0xNTMtNjguODUtMTUzLTE1M0g1MWMwIDExMi4yIDkxLjggMjA0IDIwNCAyMDRzMjA0LTkxLjggMjA0LTIwNC05MS44LTIwNC0yMDQtMjA0eiIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div id="playerWrap">
        <iframe
            width="640" height="360"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0sDg2h3M1RE?enablejsapi=1"
            frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  var playerFrame = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling.children[0].children[0];

  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player(playerFrame, {
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        document.getElementById("playerWrap").classList.add("shown");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("playerWrap").addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.seekTo(0);
    document.getElementById("playerWrap").classList.remove("shown");
  });
</script>
```

For the minified code along with further description, details and instructions, [view my blog post on the subject](https://www.maxlaumeister.com/blog/hide-related-videos-in-youtube-embeds/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
https://your_youtube_embeded_link?rel=0&showinfo=0
```

sample :

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h-_gFbNF80s?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" ></iframe>
```

`rel=0` is to remove the related videos at end of YouTube embedded video

`showinfo=0` is to remove the title inside youtube player at top

more information : [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Comment: Although the OP has already stated they've tried using `rel=0` without success?

Comment: This answer adds `showinfo=0` to that, maybe that is what is needed.

Comment: just wanted to say this code works inserted as shown. Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018  where showinfo  is depreciated after announcement of 23 Aug 2018